# TensorFlow.constant() throws TypeError with placeholder parameter (TF v1.4)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Python host language. TF v1.4.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/constant

Nearly just like docs example (above), I need to make a constant 2-D tensor populated with scalar value, in my case some mean value, which is mean of r, but r is a placeholder, not a variable, NOT a numpy array. As such, feed_dict needs to be used to fill-in placeholder r in my application.  Now a python ndarray or some python list was used in the docs example, which won't work in my application, so that's the difference.

In my application, global_bias (below) needs to be a tf.constant not a tf.variable -- because what I'm saying is, the optimizer needs to not learn it. Just leave it be, please.

Note: In my application, r is a placeholder not a variable.

```
#global_bias_value = tf.reduce_mean(r)    # tf.constant() FAILS (below)
global_bias_value = 87. # tf.constant() runs OK (below)
global_bias = tf.constant(global_bias_value, shape=(I,J)) #TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
rhat = global_bias + fm
```

So, as I said, what TF code would be used to make a constant 2-D tensor populated with scalar value, in my case some mean value, which is mean of r, but r is a placeholder, not a variable, NOT a numpy array?

Hey I tried .eval() but TF said you need a session to do that. So are you TF folks saying I need 2 sessions, run sequentially, just to do this little thing?  Or else are you saying I should bypass feed_dict to feed in my r placeholder actual data via numpy arrays in through the side door (in app memory as a python list or ndarray) plus the front door (feed_dict), which would be janky?

Thanks for clues!   I need to get one.

Comment: It sounds like you need a non-trainable variable rather than a constant, like `tf.Variable(r, trainable=False)`.  Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @Y.Luo that's an idea. I will try it.

Comment: @Y.Luo TF still throws TypeError list of tensors expected, on the line tf.constant().  I passed the parameter r to the Variable constructor to create rv along with trainable=False and then used that variable rv instead of the placeholder r in the tf.reduce_mean.  So behavior of TF did not change at all, surprisingly.  Did you have some other idea in mind as to get the value from the dict_feed into this variable constructor?

Comment: I need a constant matrix.  I need this constant matrix to be computed from a placeholder that's passed in at run time in the feed_dict. It's really simple.  It's exactly like the docs example for tf.constant() except the source of numerical data is the feed_dict not a numpy array.  It's like placeholders were forgotten by TF devs as something anyone wants to use when making a constant.  I really don't care if tf parlance calls it a constant or a variable that is nontrainable, as long as I can run a reduce_mean on the feed_dict placeholder, and it does not get optimized.

Comment: I'd also happily accept some way to make a variable contain a 2D matrix of a single value.  It was just that the constant() function seemed right but I'm not stuck on tf.constant() since there's a variable that won't train which sounds equally OK.

Comment: Sorry for pointing you to a wrong direction. Could you please check if my answer with `tf.fill` works? If not, I think a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be really helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tf.fill`(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) can give you the "constant" tensor you want in the graph. Here is my MCVE:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5], [4, 8]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.constant([[0, 4], [-1, 3], [-2, 2], [-3, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)

# The section you want
r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3, 1])
global_bias_value = tf.reduce_mean(r)
global_bias = tf.fill([4, 2], global_bias_value)

w = tf.get_variable('weight', [4, 2])
y_pred = tf.multiply(x, w) + global_bias
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(3):
  _, weight, bias = sess.run((train, w, global_bias),
                           feed_dict={r: [[1], [2], [3]]})
  print('Step: ', i)
  print('Weight: ', weight)
  print('Bias: ', bias)
```